# Auto increment file names PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, inventory

I am fairly new to the php world and have been creating an inventory tracking system for one of my side businesses. Most of the basics are working, but I am having issues with my "upload pdf" function. Even though it works and uploads the pdf file to its target location, I cannot get the file name ($docid) to be an integer that auto increments every time there is a submission so that files never have the same name. Below is the code I have working:

```
$pdfPath = "/Documents/TEST/";

$maxSize = 102400000000;

$docid = TEST;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['upload_pdf'])) { 
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filepdf']['tmp_name'])) {
            if ($_FILES['filepdf']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
                echo '<p>The file is not in PDF</p>';
            } else if ($_FILES['filepdf']['size'] > $maxSize) {
                echo '<p class="error">File is too big! Max size is =' . $maxSize . 'KB</p>';
            } else {
                $menuName = "Order_Receipt_".$docid.".pdf";
                $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filepdf']['tmp_name'], $pdfPath . $menuName);
                if ($result == 1) {                 
                    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=http://localhost/website/enter_new_order_success.html">';

                } else {
                    echo '<p class="error">Error</p>';
                }
            }
        }
```

I know I need some sort of loop to auto increment that $docid variable but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have read up on the topic, but auto increment with the if statement is throwing me off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: If this `$docid = TEST;` is your actual code, and unless `TEST` is a constant, it needs to be wrapped in quotes, just saying.

Comment: Now, I'm not good with loops, but you could use a combination of both UNIX TIMESTAMP and [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). A quick fix is `$time = time(); $unique = uniqid(); $docid = $time . "_" . $unique;` which is what I use for some of my scripts. The thing with having an auto incrementing file number, would require for you to first check if a file of the same name exists, and that would require a lot more coding than my suggestion here.

Comment: Sidenote : instead of echo'ing an `meta http-equiv refresh` tag, use `header("Location: http://localhost/website/enter_new_order_success.html");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unless you store the entries to keep track in a database or similar you could check what entries you have in your upload folder and increment it by one.

The glob function is useful for that:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
$myFiles = sort(glob('/Documents/TEST/*.pdf')); // returns an array of pdf files in the target folder. Using sort to sort the array e.g. file_1_.pdf,file_2_.pdf,file_3_.pdf, etc

//last element
$lastFile = end($myFiles);  //returns the last file in the array

//get the number and increment it by one
$number = explode('_',$lastFile);
$newNumber = $number[1] + 1; //add this to the name of your uploaded php file.

$pdfUploadedFile= "Order_Receipt_".$newNumber."_.pdf";
```

As pointed out in the comments... I find it a better idea to name it with a timestamp generated string. And also don't forget the quotes around your strings.

```
$docid = TEST;

should be:

$docid = 'TEST';
```

**Edit**

Even better would be naming it in a formatted date I suppose.

```
$pdfUploadedFile= "Order_Receipt_".date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".pdf"; // will output something like Order_receipt_2014-09-24-11-14-44.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses! Got it working using the date()/unquid() functions as part of the name... Thanks for all your tips and suggestions.